# which-like behavior for a custom search path

Tags: bash, path

I am writing a bash script that will be parsing a configuration file.  This configuration file will specify certain files, which I would like to search for in some set of directories.  I more-or-less want the behavior of `which`, except that I would like it to search my own list of directories for files that aren't executables.

Given how often this shows up (`which`, a compiler's include and library search paths), I would expect there exists some existing mechanism to do this task.

`find` would almost do what I'm looking for, except that it will choke on absolute paths (that is, `find /home/foo/bar -name /usr/local/thing.baz` won't work).

`which` will do exactly what I'm looking for, except that it will only find executable files.

How would I go about doing this task, without writing a full (and likely much slower) search routine in bash?

EDIT:

By popular demand, a couple examples

```
#Finds ./foo.a
Library foo.a

#Finds ./libraries/bar.a
Library bar.a

#Finds $MYPATH/default.b
Library default.b

#Finds $MYPATH/exampleLibraries/demo.a
Library demo.a

#Finds /home/john/program/baz.qux
Library /home/john/program/baz.qux
```

I will have a variable, such as `MYLIBPATHS=$MYPATH:$MYPATH/exampleLibraries:./:./libraries:./things` with a complete listing of possible places to look.

If it doesn't find it, I need an error; if it does find it I need [the first] absolute path to the file.

Comment: `find` will do the job but obviously `/usr/local/thing.baz` can't be found in `/home/foo/bar`.

Comment: What behavior do you expect when multiple files are found from different directories? Are those files in your configuration file listed as just names only and not as a full pathname?

Comment: @anubhava: yes; I would like an absolute pathname to remain unchanged, while relative pathnames should be resolved to an absolute pathname.

Comment: @konsolebox: Ideally files can be either shortened (at which point the script will search a set of default locations), or absolute (in which case it will be as stated).  I expect the primary use to be with relative paths, but I would not like to exclude absolute paths.

Comment: It will much clearer once you show some examples of what paths are you trying to search and what files you're trying to find.

Comment: I second posting an example of your configuration file.

Comment: @anubhava Added a few examples.

Comment: Some clarification needed, what is `Library foo.a`?

Comment: `foo.a` is a file.  `Library` is a keyword that says "find `foo.a`".  Existing code will catch the `Library` keyword (there are around a dozen others that aren't relevant here), so I just need to turn the rest of the line (that is, the text string indicating a file) into an absolute path to that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sub-optimal answer, as I wanted to avoid having to write something up in bash.  However, if someone stumbles upon this question, the following will work and is the solution I ended up using:

```
    function find_file {
            if [[ "$@" = /* && -f "$@" ]]; then
                    echo "$@"
                    return 0
            fi

            for p in "${MY_PATHS[@]}"; do
                    f="$p/$@"
                    if [[ -f "$f" ]]; then
                            echo "$f"
                            return 0
                    fi
            done

            echo "ERROR: could not locate File \"$@\"" >&2
            return 1
    }
```

This can be used by `absolute_file="$(find_file "$file")"`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try locate command?

man locate

OR

Would you be find with **-wholename** option in FIND command:

```
[jenkins@giga_aks ]$ find -name "*.sh"
./tomcat/1.sh
./tomcat/startTomcat.sh
./tomcat/startTomcat-mg.sh
./tomcat/stopTomcat.sh
./build/thidsDist/bin/deploy.sh
./compile.sh
./bin/deploy.sh
./bin/project_properties.sh
./bin/build.sh
./bin/testrunner.sh
./bin/common.sh
./src/deploy/deploy-template.sh
[jenkins@giga_aks ]$
```

This will show only under tomcat folder which exists in my current `pwd` folder location

```
[jenkins@giga_aks ]$ find -wholename  ".\/tomcat\/*.sh"
./tomcat/1.sh
./tomcat/startTomcat.sh
./tomcat/startTomcat-mg.sh
./tomcat/stopTomcat.sh
[jenkins@giga_aks ]$
```